# ipad simulator - sandbox area

Tags: iphone, ipad

Every iPhone/iPad application has its sandbox area, where I can store files. When I use the simulator this area will be somewhere in the hard disk. Is it possible to see this directory and its contents for a given application?

I am debugging an iPad app and it will be a lot easier if I can see the sandbox area contents in real time, as the app runs and creates files there.

Where do I find it?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<framework.version>/Applications/<application.uuid>/Documents
```